# What will (defun defun () 3) do?

Tags: lisp

In a CppCon talk (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80BZxujhY38 at 5:00)
Herb Sutter alluded to `defun defun 3` being somehow a problem. After
I googled it, it's still not clear to me why. Can someone elaborate?

Comment: In Common Lisp, redefining standard symbols like `defun` has undefined behaviour. The linked paper is a way to push one language up by beating another language down, which is something that happens a lot with programming language communitites.

Comment: @coredump That is actually addressed in the paper.

Comment: It is amusing seeing a paper on C++ complain about Lisp like this.  C++ is the language  *overloading the bit-shift operator to do I/O* seemed like a good idea to someone.

Comment: @tfb Exactly. `'Image` is clearly the best way to do IO

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn: I have no idea what that means.  If you're talking about `quote` in Lisp: that's nothing to do with IO, at all.

Comment: Ada uses the Image attribute to get the string representation of something, which you would then pass to the `Text_IO.Put_Line` procedure. Just another example of a programming language that does things in wildly different ways for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a [comment from the same video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80BZxujhY38&lc=Ugx7pvHUMYiBXIXOm5x4AaABAg.8lkohnwbbWJ8lpRoYhZ8lR):

> **Herb Sutter**
>
> See also the paper, P0707 (http://wg21.link/p0707), and search for "defun." Lisp defun (and Scheme define) lets you define a function... but in Lisp and Scheme you can even redefine built-in functions and macros, including defun/define itself which is what "defun defun" / "define define" does. Here's a sample related StackExchange question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/375/symbols-value-as-a-variable-is-void-defun-when-reloading-emacs .
>
> I'm not interested in doing anything like that in C++, and there's nothing like that in my proposal, you can't change any definitions (including of this class after it is defined), you can't reach out and affect anyone else's type or code, the only thing you can do is participate in generating the one-time-and-then-immutable definition of this class you're writing right now which is nice and localized and bounded... and still very powerful.

The [linked paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0707r4.pdf) contains this section:

> **5.2.1 Problems in other languages**
>
> In Lisp and related languages, programmers can redefine other people’s code and even global language facilities (e.g., the notorious `(defun defun () 3)` in Lisp, or `(define define () 3)` in Scheme). This is powerful, but undisciplined (causes arbitrary global effects up to and including breaking the language itself), fragile (Lisp makes it notoriously easy to write “write-only” code that is difficult to review, read, and maintain), and causes programs to be tightly coupled among their components and with their developer’s environment (Lisp makes it notoriously easy to write code whose meaning depends on local customizations, is hard to share, and when shared is hard to compose with other code that came from an environment with competing assumptions).<sup>4</sup>

The footnote says:

> <sup>4</sup> Various incarnations and offshoots of Lisp attempted to mitigate this problem in various ways without actually taking away the root cause: Common Lisp added the guarantee that all symbols in the package `COMMON-LISP` are protected and must not be redefined by user code otherwise you get undefined behavior; although this provides some protection for the standard facilities, it does not solve the general problem because it still permits one set of user code to redefine things in another set of user code. Also, implementations like SBCL attempted to further improve the problem by providing ways to “lock” packages so their contents cannot be accidentally redefined; however, even SBCL also provides ways to “unlock” them again.

Comment: `it does not solve the general problem because it still permits one set of user code to redefine things in another set of user code`. In Lisp this is seen as a useful feature and not a problem.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Agreed. It all depends on how you set your priorities. Lisp is much like Perl in this regard (see also e.g. [`make_immutable` in metaclasses](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::MOP::Class#Class-Immutability)).

Comment: CL has locks and if one chooses to ignore those you are on your own. In Scheme you need to go back to R5RS to have this as a problem. From R6RS you `import` the standard library and you can redefine it in your own code, but you can not affect a library written by someone else. If you take an object and call a method on that object you have no idea what method you are calling if your type specification is vague. IMHO that is exactly the same as defun defun, but with classes. BTW I'm no fan of Python, but their way of monkey patching is very nice.

Comment: When I used lisp machines, I had patches which got loaded which redefined bits of the system to make them work properly ('redefining things in another set of user code').  This was called 'fixing bugs'.

Comment: Redefining standard functions in C and C++ is certainly possible, via undefined behavior. `malloc` and other C library functions are "weak symbols" in some modern environments and can be overridden by the program.  This is a critical feature for multi-standard compliance because ISO C allows a program to to use `read` as an external name, yet that is also a POSIX function; so there has to be a way to provide the POSiX function without interfering with an ISO C program that wants to use that name.

Comment: C and C++ programs don't redefine by running code, but by loading object files; however, that is even something that can be done at run time with shared libraries. ELF shared libraries allow a newly loaded object to override an already satisfied linking reference in the executable or previously loaded objects.

Comment: @Kaz We're not talking about swapping out the definition of one symbol for another. This is changing the way the language itself works, e.g. by redefining what `class` does.

Comment: @melpomene `defun` is a macro. You can redefine macros in C and C++: `#undef mac` `#define mac(blah) ...`.  Like in Lisp, this has no effect on already compiled code. If someone has obliterated `defun` in their Lisp image, I can still compile files with `defun` in my Lisp image, and give them the compiled modules that will load, because they aren't expanding my `defun` macros.